# How to convert XML Object to JAXB java obejct?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, unmarshalling

my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns1:oadrPayload xmlns:ns1="http://openadr.org/oadr-2.0b/2012/07" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/emix/2011/06/siscale" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns4="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/emix/2011/06/power" xmlns:ns5="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns6="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/energyinterop/201110" xmlns:ns7="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/energyinterop/201110/payloads" xmlns:ns8="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:icalendar-2.0" xmlns:ns9="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:icalendar-2.0:stream" xmlns:ns10="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:ns11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/emix/2011/06" xmlns:ns12="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmldsig11#" xmlns:ns13="http://openadr.org/oadr-2.0b/2012/07/xmldsig-properties" xmlns:ns14="urn:un:unece:uncefact:codelist:standard:5:ISO42173A:2010-04-07">
    <ns1:oadrSignedObject>
        <ns1:oadrCreatedPartyRegistration ns6:schemaVersion="2.0b">
            <ns6:eiResponse>
                <ns6:responseCode>200</ns6:responseCode>
                <ns6:responseDescription>OK</ns6:responseDescription>
                <ns7:requestID>16ACD8A205</ns7:requestID>
            </ns6:eiResponse>
        </ns1:oadrCreatedPartyRegistration>
    </ns1:oadrSignedObject>
</ns1:oadrPayload>
```

I created java classes with 
@XmlRootElement and @XmlElement but it give namespace error Please help me to convert this string to java object

My code java code

```
File file = new File("Test.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(OadrPayload.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    OadrPayload stationSearch = (OadrPayload) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

Comment: Provide the classes too.

Answer (score 0):

here is one example- you can follow-

Quiz.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<quiz>
   <question>
      <questionText>Who is the author of this column?</questionText>
      <answer correct='N'>Pat McClellan</answer>
      <answer correct='N'>Darrel Plant</answer>
      <answer correct='N'>Gary Rozensweig</answer>
      <answer correct='Y'>Will Turnage</answer>
   </question>
   <question>
      <questionText>Who is Director Online's Technical Editor?</questionText>
      <answer correct='N'>Pat McClellan2</answer>
      <answer correct='N'>Darrel Plant2</answer>
      <answer correct='N'>Gary Rozensweig2</answer>
      <answer correct='Y'>Will Turnage2</answer>
   </question>
</quiz>
```

Java code for XML to object-

```
public class ReadXmlFileCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     try {
         //create object from xml
        File file = new File("C:\\Qstn.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Quiz.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Quiz customer = (Quiz) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        for(Question qs:customer.getQuestion())
        {
            System.out.println(qs.getQuestionText());
            System.out.println(qs.getAnswer().get(0).getCorrect());
        }
        ////create xml from object
        File file1 = new File("C:\\file1.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext1 = JAXBContext.newInstance(Quiz.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext1.createMarshaller();

        // output pretty printed
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, file1);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);

      } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
}
```

now create a Quij.java,Question.java and Answer.java thrre file
and work is done.